# How to create onUpdate function with callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to create a copy of a game called "Hill Climb Racing" using pixi.js and matter.js. I have found a simple scene manager and scene object written in TypeScript and I converted it to JavaScript but some part of code is not working... I would like to use the function `onUpdate` like this: `gameplay.onUpdate(function() {} );`, but I do not know how to call the callback in `onUpdate` function by function `this.update()`.

```js
var callback = function() {}
this.onUpdate = function(callback) {
  if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
    callback();
    console.log("looP");
  }
}
this.update = function() {
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I prefer to show you how to pass a callback as "local" function so it will be more clear. (And this is usually use case)

```js
this.onUpdate = function(callback) {
    if(callback && typeof callback == "function"){
        callback();
        console.log("looP");
    }
}
this.update = function() {
  this.onUpdate(() => {
    console.log('onUpdate callback');
  });
}
```

For example:

```js
function myObj() {
  this.onUpdate = function(callback) {
    if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
      callback();
      console.log("looP");
    }
  }
  this.update = function() {
    this.onUpdate(() => {
      console.log('onUpdate callback');
    });
  }
}

const a = new myObj();
//a.update();
a.onUpdate(() => {
  console.log('this is my callback!');
});
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but i want to use function onUpdate in other files. I mean i write
    a.onUpdate(function() {
        somethingToDo();
    });
and i have that i shuld name it event i think.

Comment: gameplay.onUpdate(() => {
  engine.update(engine, 1000 / 60);
  scoobyCar.update();
  console.log("test");
});
Thats what i'm using, but it's not working. I'm trying to find issue but i can't :(

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? What is the chance that you can create a **working** example code (https://jsbin.com, https://jsfiddle.net, https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Ok,i created example here: https://jsbin.com/nijetiqoxi/edit?html,js,output
Problem is that: gameplay.onUpdate(() => {
  engine.update(engine, 1000 / 60);
  scoobyCar.update();
  console.log("test");
});
On the end of javascript is not working

Comment: The problem is something else. You can see it in the `console` - `Cannot read property 'onUpdate' of undefined`. And that's because you try to set `gameplay` a property while it still `undefined`. Only after `loader.load`, `gameplay` it initialising`. The solution is to move the `gameplay.onUpdate` **into** `loader.load` callback.

Comment: After that, you will get another error but it has nothing with `callback` mechanism.

Comment: So yeah, i have fixed all errors i think but there is a problem, the callback function onUpdate runs only once. When this.onUpdate() and this.update in Scene.js are basicly loops.